# Spring Roo generates a lot of queries

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-roo, many-to-one

I'm trying to learn Spring Roo, and I'm doing my little application.
I have product class:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity(table = "TOWARY")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAZWA")
    private String name;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private int version;
}
```

And a fact class:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity(table = "FACTS")
public class Fact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "KWOTA")
    private float kwota;

    @Column(name = "NCZAS")
    private int nczas;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private int version;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_TOWAR")
    private Product product;
}
```

After Sprinng Roo has done it magic, I'm starting application and I see webpage. Nice work, so little code and it's almost working. 
When doing preview of products it's working fine:

```
Hibernate: select product0_.ID as ID0_, product0_.NAZWA as NAZWA0_, product0_.VERSION as VERSION0_ from TOWARY product0_
Hibernate: select product0_.ID as ID0_, product0_.NAZWA as NAZWA0_, product0_.VERSION as VERSION0_ from TOWARY product0_ limit ?
Hibernate: select count(product0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from TOWARY product0_ limit ?
```

But when I'm viewing facts I have a lot of queries (basically one for each fact table row):

```
Hibernate: select fact0_.ID as ID1_, fact0_.KWOTA as KWOTA1_, fact0_.NCZAS as NCZAS1_, fact0_.ID_TOWAR as ID5_1_, fact0_.VERSION as VERSION1_ from FACTS fact0_
Hibernate: select product0_.ID as ID0_0_, product0_.NAZWA as NAZWA0_0_, product0_.VERSION as VERSION0_0_ from TOWARY product0_ where product0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select product0_.ID as ID0_0_, product0_.NAZWA as NAZWA0_0_, product0_.VERSION as VERSION0_0_ from TOWARY product0_ where product0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select product0_.ID as ID0_0_, product0_.NAZWA as NAZWA0_0_, product0_.VERSION as VERSION0_0_ from TOWARY product0_ where product0_.ID=?
...
```

After searching I have found "N+1 selects problem" posts. Am I right – that also my problem?
I thought that `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` forces hibernate to use join and not subselects. 

In aspect files I've found generated query which is responsible for fetching my data:

```
public static List<Fact> Fact.findAllFacts() {
    return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Fact o", Fact.class).getResultList();
}
```

How can I force Spring Roo to use join? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `FetchType.EAGER` from the ManyToOne to `FetchType.LAZY`. Eager-loading is fetching the whole object graph. And I'm pretty-sure you can get rid of the `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` annotation.

Comment: looks like we can specify these options with roo commands too, nice ! https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-250